Anaconda will not open after installing PostgreSQL
I was previously able to open Anaconda, jupyter notebook, and Spyder, etc., but after installing PostgreSQL, I cannot open Anaconda, Jupyter notebook, or  Spyder at all. Powershell shows an error that I don't understand, much less know how to fix. I have uninstalled and re-installed Anaconda multiple times.
I need an "explain like I'm five years old" explanation.
Here is the error message that appears when opening Powershell.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\misha\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'
Invoke-Expression : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Command' because it is an empty string.
At C:\Users\misha\anaconda3\shell\condabin\Conda.psm1:76 char:36
+         Invoke-Expression -Command $activateCommand;
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing Anaconda. I've looked at the questions already on Stack Overflow and could find nothing that helped.
